# Write postgres output to a file using php

Tags: php, file, postgresql

I want to get the output of a postgres query written into a file. I am using php to connect to the remote database and execute the query. Here is the sample code.

```
$connection_id=pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=test password=test");
$psql="select example from sample limit 180";
$result=pg_query($connection_id,$psql);
```

I have the query executed, but I am unable to write it to a file. How do I do that?

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write the query result into a file directly. The result returned by [pg_query](https://www.php.net/manual/function.pg-query.php) is no string with any data that can be printed or written into a file. It's either an error status (`false`) or some kind of "reference" to result data kept for this query.

If `$result` isn't `==false` and if PostgreSQL could find any rows as a result for your query, then you can [fetch these rows](https://www.php.net/manual/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php). But that's an extra step. It's not included in `pg_query`. In order to check how many result rows were found you can use the function [`pg_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.pg-num-rows.php).

Then you can iterate through the result set using [`pg_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php). This is only one suitable function. There are a few more, e.g. `pg_fetch_row`.

Here's some small example code (quick & dirty without much error handling):

```
<?php 

    // Set the output of this script to plain text
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    $conn = pg_connect("...");   // insert your data here
    if (!$conn) die ("Couldn't connect.");

    $result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT example FROM ...");  // TODO
    // Check for error and check the number of rows found:
    if ((!$result) || (pg_num_rows($result) < 1)) {
        pg_close();
        echo "Couldn't find any data for your query. Maybe the query is wrong (error) or there are no matching lines.";
        exit;
    }

    // Line counter for screen output
    $i = 1;
    
    // Open file.   (Important: Script must have write permission for the directory!)
    $fileHandle = fopen("./myresults.txt", "w");
    
    // Do this as long as you can find more result rows:
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // Write value to the output that is sent to the web browser client:
        echo "Line " . $i . ": \"" . strip_tags($row['example']) . "\"\r\n";
        // Write the same value as a new line into the opened file:
        fwrite ($fileHandle, $row['example'] . "\r\n";
        // Increase line number counter:
        $i++;
    }
    
    // Close the file:
    fclose ($fileHandle);
    
    // Free the result / used memory:
    pg_free_result($result);
    
    pg_close();
    
?>
```